# Problems showing all Articles that have a certain Category in their list of categories?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Problems showing all Articles that have a certain Category in their list of categories?

```
Articles
has_and_belongs_to_many Categories

Categories
has_and_belongs_to_many Articles

class CreateJoinTableArticleCategory < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_join_table :articles, :categories do |t|
      # t.index [:article_id, :category_id]
      # t.index [:category_id, :article_id]
    end
  end
end
```

Models and migrations are fine, seeding is fine info in rails console is fine but in the Controller I have problems showing all Articles for a certain category I get from the URL:

```
    class CategoriesController < ApplicationController

      def show
        @user = current_user
        @categories = Category.all
        @category = Category.friendly.find(params[:slug])

      #@a = Article.where(category_id: @category, published: true)
      #@a = Article.left_outer_joins(:categories).where("categories.category_id = @category")
      #@a = Article.joins("LEFT JOIN articles_categories ON category.id = articles_categories.id")
      #@a = Article.includes(:categories).where(@category)


        @q = Question.where(category_id: @category, published: true)
        @articles = (@q + @a).sort_by(&:created_at).reverse.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 4)
      end

    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with ".friendly" (why do you use it?), but are you sure you only get 1 Category with that? If so your first @a should work or the easier version

```
@category.articles.where(published: true)
```

Have you tried it without the @q just to test it. I see there the only source for problems.

PS: your code will have big performance problems. First you are loading all Categories and later all Articles and Questions for 1 Category, sorting them by Ruby and totally disable advantages of pagination.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously I don't know how exactly your data is structured but this should work when changed around slightly to suit your needs.

```
Articles.includes(:categories).where('category.name = ?', 'category_name').references(:categories)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@category = Category.friendly.find(params[:slug])
@category.articles.published
```

there published is scope created in article model

In Article model create scope:

```
scope :published, -> { where(published: true) }
```